# Singleton not showing parametrized methods in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

i implemented a singleton exaclty like this tutorial

http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/

When i use it, it works fine showing me properties but methods i can only see the ones withour parameters.

```
@interface MyManager : NSObject {
    NSString *someProperty;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *someProperty;
+(void) methodOK;
+(void)methodiCantSee:(NSString *)name;
+ (id)sharedManager;

@end
```

I can do this

```
MyManager *sharedManager = [MyManager sharedManager];
sharedManager.methodOk
```

But i cant do this

```
MyManager *sharedManager = [MyManager sharedManager];
sharedManager.methodICantSee:@"MyName";
```

Plase help!

Comment: What is `sharedManager.methodICantSee:@"MyName";` supposed to mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made all of your methods as class methods. Make them instance methods.

```
@interface MyManager : NSObject {
    NSString *someProperty;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *someProperty;
- (void) methodOK;
- (void)methodiCantSee:(NSString *)name;

+ (id)sharedManager;

@end
```

And please learn the proper syntax for calling a method:

```
[sharedManager methodOk];

[sharedManager methodCantSee:@"some string"];
```

Given these mistakes, may I suggest you find a good tutorial on the basics of the Objective-C programming language. Learning the basics now will save you a ton of time down the road.

Comment: I knew already the proper sintax, but was so frustated than didnt know what was the right way to put it. Changing from + to - worked.

Answer (score 1):

To call any method that has a parameter, you'll have to use Objective-C syntax in Objective-C.

Try out:

`[sharedManager methodICantSee:@"MyName"];`

Using dot syntax is allowed for methods that take no parameters, and have a non-void return type.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, its because `sharedManager` is of type `id` which literally means any object.

if you want to be more specific please use `instancetype` then you can call the dot syntax as you have demonstrated in your example.

e.g.

```
+ (instancetype)sharedManager;
```

but as @rmaddy said, if its a method you are calling you should use the square brackets.

**Edit:**

Your methods:

```
+(void) methodOK;
+(void)methodiCantSee:(NSString *)name;
```

are defined as class methods which means they can be accessed through the class and not have any state, this can be done as follows:

```
[MyManager methodOK];
[MyManager methodiCantSee:@"some_string"];
```

If you want instance methods on the singleton object (if you want to interact with some state if the object) you must define the method with a `-` and access it through an instance of the class. This can be done as such:

```
-(void)methodOK;
-(void)methodiCantSee:(NSString *)name;


MyManager *sharedManager = [MyManager sharedManager];
[sharedManager methodOk];
[sharedManager methodiCantSee:@"some_string"];
```

Good luck on your venture, hope I helped.

Comment: Using `id` as the return type is not the issue at all (and is perfectly valid - though using `instancetype` is a modern improvement). The variable `sharedManager` is not declared as `id` but as `MyManager`. Xcode is confused for 2 reasons: 1) The methods are class methods, not instance methods. 2) The OP is trying to use property syntax to call methods.

Comment: @rmaddy no worries, I am only here to help, a few down-votes wont stop me :) - I missed they are class methods OP is trying to call. If it was up-to me I would recommend against a singleton object and go for a single instance at-least so you can unit test it. Ill update my answer to reflect this.